# How to get last day of the month

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I obtain the last day of the month with the timestamp being 11:59:59 PM?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This will give you last day of current month.

```
var t= new Date();
alert(new Date(t.getFullYear(), t.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59));
```

Comment: No need for two Date objects: `t.setMonths(t.getMonth()+1, 0, 23, 59, 59, 0)`.

Comment: what represent the number after getMonth() please

Comment: This is not a correct answer... The GMT is not conserved

Answer (score 41):

```js
function LastDayOfMonth(Year, Month) {
  return new Date((new Date(Year, Month, 1)) - 1);
}

console.log(LastDayOfMonth(2009, 11))
```

Example:

```
> LastDayOfMonth(2009, 11)
Mon Nov 30 2009 23:59:59 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Comment: +1 but sets time to 23:59:59.999. Maybe better to set seconds to 59.000 so `... Month, 1)) - 1000)`. :-)

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want to leave 999ms out of a range calculation

Comment: Same, the GMT is not conserved and you will get weird results when manipulating the created date object, see csukcc answer for a correct implementation

Answer (score 7):

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log(d);
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1); // set month as next month
console.log(d);
d.setDate(0); // get the last day of previous month
console.log(d);
```

Here is output from the code above:
Thu Oct 03 2013 11:34:59 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)
Sun Nov 03 2013 11:34:59 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
Thu Oct 31 2013 11:34:59 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)

Comment: You could simplify this a little more by passing the date to `setMonth` like so: `d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1, 0)`

Comment: This doesnt set the timestamp "11:59:59 PM" as requested in the question.

Answer (score 2):

```
var d = new Date();
m = d.getMonth(); //current month
y = d.getFullYear(); //current year
alert(new Date(y,m,1)); //this is first day of current month
alert(new Date(y,m+1,0)); //this is last day of current month
```

Comment: I've tried this, and `alert(new Date(y,m+1,0));` gives you the last day for the next month.

Comment: @mickburkejnr you may want to check again, I just tried it and it works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Last day of the month

```
now = new Date
lastDayOfTheMonth = new Date(1900+now.getYear(), now.getMonth()+1, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var month = 1; // 1 for January
var d = new Date(2015, month, 0);
console.log(d); // last day in January
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes all you have is a text version of the current month, ie: April 2017.

```
//first and last of the current month
var current_month = "April 2017";
var arrMonth = current_month.split(" ");
var first_day = new Date(arrMonth[0] + " 1 " + arrMonth[1]);

//even though I already have the values, I'm using date functions to get year and month
//because month is zero-based
var last_day = new Date(first_day.getFullYear(), first_day.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59);

//use moment,js to format       
var start = moment(first_day).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
var end = moment(last_day).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of these answers are missing one thing or another. After playing with most of them I came up with the following that gives you the last possible millisecond of the month.

```
let testDate = new Date();
console.log(getMonthEnd(testDate));

function getMonthEnd(value) {
    return new Date(value.getFullYear(), value.getMonth() + 1, 0, 23, 59, 59, 999);
}
```

Probably missing something in this one too but seems to cover all my requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code to get the last day of the current month

```
getLastDayOfMonth() {
  const date = new Date()
  const month = date.getMonth() + 1
  const year = date.getFullYear()
  return new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cal.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DATE));

Date lastDayOfMonth = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: That's some weird javascript you got there.

Comment: The question is about javascript, not Java! This answer should be removed.

Answer (score -1):

Do not forget month started with 0 so +1 in month too.

```
let enddayofmonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate();
```