# how can I use jQuery monthpicker in primefaces?

Tags: primefaces

I want to get a month picker as an input field.

I came to know about jQuery monthpicker.

how can I use that in primefaces?

Comment: You can find your answer at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609517/primefaces-calendar-component-show-only-month-and-year/15615332#15615332

Answer (score 0):

I have not come across Prime faces but why don't you use Jquery UI it has a built in calendar. You could easily adapt the code to just output the month.

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

```
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm' }).val();
```

Thanks