# How to show a calendar per month on primefaces / jsf / jquery

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, primefaces

Is there a way to show a calendar with 1 month only? Each calendar should show all the days of that month. For example:

```
Calendar1 = January 1-31 
Calendar2 = February 1-28/29
... and so on.
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609517/primefaces-calendar-component-show-only-month-and-year

Comment: No this one is different, it shows the month and year. What I want is a calendar per month. For example in a year, I need 12 calendars: January, Feb..., Dec with each calendar having days of the month.

Answer (score 0):

You can do by some ways, my approach is use jquery, when calendar is focused, we need to disable `a` tag which use to `next` or `previous`:

```
<p:calendar onfocus="$('#ui-datepicker-div a').unbind();" />
```