# Primefaces Calendar without Year

Tags: primefaces, calendar

I need to build a page with all days of the year splitted month by month and the user will select multiples days, according they needed. I tried use the Calendar component from PrimeFaces, but unsuccessifully because it doesn't have a way to disable de year field from dates.

There is another way to do this using any component from PrimeFaces?

ps. I'm using version 6.1 of Primefaces.

Comment: Unrelated to your question comment: Not every year has Feb. 29. How many days in your hypothetical year 365 or 366 (leap)?

Comment: For your inspiration: [Primefaces calendar component show only month and year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15609517/primefaces-calendar-component-show-only-month-and-year).

Comment: @VasilLukach The day 29'feb of the leap year will be always ignored.