# ExtJS 4.2 DatePicker get the first day and last day in the calendar

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc

I have an `ExtJS` `datepicker` where I disable some dates so the user can't select them.

After the calendar is `renderer` I send to the server the current date and the server sends back an array of days to disable, so the visual result is the following:

[image]

The problem I have is that I don't know the first and last day showed in the datepicker.

> In this image the first day is 08/31/2014 and the last day is 09/11/2014. How can I get those dates, so I can tell my server to check if within that range I have to disable any date.

In the calendar example the "yellow marked dates" have to been disabled.

[image]

Any clue? Appreciate in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8ms

this uses minDate, maxDate with disabledDates, disabledDays combination..to enable particular days and disable all other days.

Answer (score 1):

You could arbitrarily set the minValue to this month's first day and maxValueto this month's last day and then assume this on the backend side.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Date-cfg-minValue

Here's how to get current month's first and last day

[Get first and last date of current month with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery)