# Convert DateTime to string in Where Predicate

Tags: javascript, breeze

I would like to create a Predicate that allows the user to search a date for a text string.

```
breeze.Predicate.create('startDate', 'contains', filterValue);
```

The filter value is entered by the user eg. `'2014-06-'`

`'contains'` will not work with a DateTime type.

Is is possible to convert the `'startDate'` to a formatted string type when creating the Predicate?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the date format is fixed to yyyy-mm-dd then your best bet is probably converting the partial date to a real date.

- If the filter value has more than 7 characters assume it is year and month and parse it accordingly.  Create two dates, first day of the month (`filterStartDate`) and last day of the month (`filterEndDate`). You can have a look [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572682/1980659) to do that. With those two dates you will be able to mimic a `contains` with something like :

```js
Predicate
.create('startDate', '>=', filterStartDate)
.or(    'startDate', '<',  filterEndDate);
```

- If the filter value has less than 7 characters assume it is only the year. Parse the year (`filterYear`) and do something like :

```js
Predicate
  .create('startDate', '>=', new Date(Date.UTC(filterYear, 0, 1))) 
  .or(    'startDate', '<',  new Date(Date.UTC(filterYear, 11, 30)));
```

Of course if the filter value is a full date then look for this date.