# JavaScript Date Increment from a certain date

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div id="date">
    <script>
        newDate();
    </script>
</div>
<div id="date">
    <script>
        newDate() + 1;
    </script>
</div>
<div id="date">
    <script>
        newDate() + 2;
    </script>
</div>
```

Above is the HTML that I want to apply the script to.

```
function newDate() {
    var _date = new Date("April 10");
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = _date;
}
```

Essentially, what I'm trying to do is write a script that will show the date in the format "Friday, April 10th" and when I go to the next div and do the script it will produce "Saturday, April 11th". But right now I can't even get it to post the date. Could someone point me in a direction that would simplify and help me out?

Comment: "I can't even it get to post the date" --- what does it mean? Btw, do you really have 3 divs with the same `id`?

Comment: Date() won't recognize "April 10" because it's not specific enough. you can use a more forgiving parser like moment.js. you are also trying to add something to a function return, but you never do anything with the modified values, and the function doesn't return a value to modify. you probably want to pass the days to newDate like `newDate(2)`, and then define a formap parameter in newDate() to use to offset the new Date.

Comment: Your function doesn’t return anything, so the implicit return value will just be `undefined` … and trying to add a number to that will only result in `NaN` (Not a Number)

Comment: And an id must be unique within an HTML document.

Comment: As for how to add a certain period of time to a date in JavaScript, start your research(!) here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=javascript+add+date

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps you to get started on the correct path. I used Jquery to make things a little bit simpler.

**What is going on here**

Basically I iterate through each date div by using

```
.each()
```

I initialize the date of today. And I create a function that will create a day object from the current date. Then I extract the correct parts using

```
.getDay()
.getMonth()
```

**What you need to do**

Now all you need to take care of is dealing with end of the month. To do this create variables.

```
var currentmonth=
var currentyear=
```

Get the last date of the month and if you reach the end of the month increment things in a logical way. This will help you to solve that problem.

[Get first and last date of current month with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Starter code:

https://jsfiddle.net/mughdmvn/

Let  me know if you have any other questions

```
var current = 5;
var create = function(){
    return new Date(2015, 4, current);
}
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
       "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

$(".date").each(function(){
    init = create();
    $(this).text(""+ monthNames[init.getMonth() - 1] + ", " +             init.getDate());
    current++;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give each div a separate id and iterate through them using a `for` loop.

```
<div id="date1">
</div>
<div id="date2">
</div>
<div id="date3">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thisDate = new Date(2015, 4, 9);
    for(var i = 1; i <= 3; i ++) {
        var thisDate = thisDate.setDate(thisDate.getDate() + 1);
        var dateDiv = document.getElementById("date" + i);
        dateDiv.innerHTML = thisDate.toDateString();
    }
</script>
```

Note that the `toDateString()` function returns the day of the week, followed by month, day of month, and then year.

For example:

```
Fri Apr 10 2015
```