# Configure kendo-date-picker to restrict dates into current month

Tags: kendo-ui, datepicker, calendar, restriction

I have used Kendo Datepicker (kendo-date-picker)into one of my projects and now I want to restrict the date selection into current month. Yes, I can do it programmatically, but I want to know whether is there any configuration option to restrict the date selection into current month.

For example, if I am in April 2015, I should not be able to select any date outside of April 2015.

Comment: Are you using Razor or Javascript?

Comment: The Kendo Datepicker has a `min` and a `max` setting that limits the selectable dates, as you probably know. However, you must calculate those min and max dates. There is no setting for "currentMonth" or anything like it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     // JavaScript counts months from 0 to 11. January is 0. December is 11.

     var date = new Date();
     var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
     var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

     $("#datepicker").kendoDatePicker({
      min: firstDay,
      max: lastDay
     });
});
```

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ycrhm9n6/1/)

Comment: its not acceptable. because you need to calculate the end date manually for each of the months. I didn't want this. thanks for your reply.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can override the style to hide the other month dates.

```
.k-other-month {
    visibility: hide;
}
```