# Get the start date and end date by passing month and year in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I wanted to know as how to get the start date and end date by passing the month name to a function like:

```
var myMonth="September 2015"
```

?

I tried this link [Get first and last date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery) but the input is different  from the one that is in the link

Comment: There is no such a function available built-in. Good news though: you can implement one yourself.

Comment: 1. The question is unclear, you should show the input and expected output. 2. You should show your efforts to solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By your question I think you want to get the particular months first date and last date.
I can suggest the following:

For first date:

```
var myMonth="September 2015" 
myMonth = "1 "+myMonth;
var d = new Date(myMonth);
d.getDate(); // will give the start date of the month
```

For last date:

```
var myMonth="September 2015" 
myMonth = "1 "+myMonth;
var checkDate = new Date(myMonth);
var d = new Date(checkDate.getFullYear(), checkDate.getMonth() + 1, 0);
d.getDate(); // this will return the last date of the month
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/swaprks/5z2s2myt/

Comment: `new Date("September 2015")` returns `Invalid Date`

Comment: Can I get the date in this formar :StartDate:01-09-2015 and EndDate: 30-09-2015?

Comment: You can get the date object and from that you can make the date as : dateObj.getDate() +"-"+ (dateObj.getMonth()+1) +"-"+ dateObj.getFullYear(). Plus one for month because it starts from 0.