# How to get start date and end date of month in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have only month e.g : '**May**'

from this i want to get **start** **date** and **last** **date** of 'May' month using java-script.

Thank you.

Comment: The start date is always "1" (e.g. "May 1")

Comment: It already answered on stackoverflow [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate last day of month in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/222309/calculate-last-day-of-month-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

The first date of any  month would be 1. As far as the last date is concerned you can use [moveToLastDayOfMonth](https://code.google.com/archive/p/datejs/wikis/APIDocumentation.wiki#moveToLastDayOfMonth)

> Moves the date to the last day of the month.

or you can use this way:

```js
var month = 4; 
var d = new Date(2016, month + 1, 0);
alert(d);
```

Comment: need `-1` instead of `0` to get the length of current month.

Comment: @dandavis:- I have already set the month as `month+1`. So I dont think its required.

Comment: @dandavis:- `i want to get start date and last date of 'May' month using java-script.`. So start date is always 1 which I have mentioned and last date would be 31 in case of `may`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
date = new Date(2016, 5, 1);
lastdate = new Date(date - 1);
console.log(lastdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

start date always will be 1 and,
for last date you can try this,

```
var date = new Date();
var lastDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your respond.

I found this answer.

```
var month = 'MAY'
var a = '1-'+month+'-2015';
        var date = new Date(a);
        var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
        var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
        console.log(firstDay);
        console.log(lastDay);
```

Answer (score 0):

I created months array for check month value for JS standard date.Then get  date format **Date(year,month,day)** as you want

```
var months = ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
var month = "May";
for(var i in months){
    if(months[i] == month){
        month = i;
    }
}
var s = new Date(2016, month, 1);
var e = new Date(2016, ++month, 0);
console.log(s+"\n"+e);
```