# Eventhandling / to get first day in a calendar

Tags: javascript

I looking for sample javascript code that shows how to get the first day of summer with event handling...

I had

```
var $ = function(id) { return document.getElementById(id);...
```

however im not sure since I'm just begnining to cover event handling

I thought about using a div also, when the user clicks a div with the mouse to display a message like

The first day summer is .......

Comment: Looks like you are requiring a code to complete your homework.

Comment: ? I dont attend school, I'm currently trying to see what the layout looks like

Comment: This question is too specific for stack overflow. But start by breaking it into steps. Here's some code that finds the first day of the month in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery now see if you can modify that to get the first day of summer. Then, if you get stuck, update your question above with a more specific problem.