# Javascript get start of the month

Tags: javascript

How to get the start of the month in date format e.g. 01-05-2017?

I have already seen

[Get first and last date of current month with javascript or jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: As you've seen how to get the first date - just .toString() it with the desired format...

Comment: how????????????

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly `toLocaleString()` might do what you want.
For example:

`lastDay.toLocaleString('en-GB', {day: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric'});`

[For more info (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Replace locale with any that suits your desired formatting.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the date we need to convert it to desired string format.

01 is the day and may be a constant since every beginning of the month starts from 1.

[getMonth](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) returns number of the month starting from 0 so we need a little function to format it.

```js
var date = new Date();
var startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var startDateString = '01-' + fotmatMonth(startDate.getMonth()) + '-' + startDate.getFullYear();
console.log(startDateString);

function fotmatMonth(month) {
  month++;
  return month < 10 ? '0' + month : month;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var date = new Date();
console.log(getStartOfMonthDateAsString(date));

function getStartOfMonthDateAsString() {        
  function zerosPad(number, numOfZeros) {
    var zero = numOfZeros - number.toString().length + 1;
    return Array(+(zero > 0 && zero)).join("0") + number;
  }

  var day = zerosPad(1, 2);
  var month = zerosPad((date.getMonth() + 1), 2);
  var year = date.getFullYear();

  return day + '-' + month + '-' + year;
}
```

Comment: date.getMonth() + 1 will return 5 when we need 05