# javascript return wrong first date and last dates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I found this code can be used to find the first date and the last date of a current month.

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
```

Today is 11/1/2018

I used this piece of code for a calendar I am developing for one of my projects. Even though it should return first day of the month as `2018-01-01T18:30:00.000Z` it returns the first day as `2017-12-31T18:30:00.000Z` and the last date as `2018-01-30T18:30:00.000Z`.

But there are 31 days in January. So what is wrong with this code?

I found the code from a stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: That is why i have mentioned that question as the link. it does not work. thats the problem

Comment: @mersocarlin Why link the same question that he did in his question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the code. The inconsistency you see here is actually the timezone difference. Your plugin is printing the date in ISO string. To get this string in your own locale, use `toLocaleString()` on the date objects:

```js
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);

console.log(firstDay.toLocaleString());
console.log(lastDay.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Oh thas was the problem. Thank you so much