# startOfMonth returns last day of month before

Tags: javascript, date, jestjs, date-fns

So it's pretty straight forwards:

```
import startOfMonth from 'date-fns/start_of_month';

export const getFirstDayThisMonth = date => {
  const firstDay = startOfMonth(date);
  return firstDay;
};
```

given input (for example):
`1987-02-02T00:00:00.000Z`

it returns:
`1987-01-31T23:00:00.000Z`

The error is reproduced exactly when trying to produce the first date according to the method mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572682/4136445):

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
```

The error comes when running jest-tests and can't be reproduced in the console where it works as expected:

```
const day1 = new Date('1987-02-02');
undefined
const day2 = new Date(day1.getFullYear(),day1.getMonth(),1)
undefined
day2
Sun Feb 01 1987 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

---

If in the second solution I also set the fourth argument (hour) to 1, it correctly handles:

`1987-02-02T00:00:00.000Z`
returning `1987-02-01T00:00:00.000Z`

and

`2001-03-03T00:00:00.000Z`
returning `2001-03-01T00:00:00.000Z`

but

`2002-04-04T00:00:00.000Z`
returns `2002-03-31T23:00:00.000Z`

I'm really at loss as to what could be causing this issue, it feels like there's some rollover to the previous date when the time is set to 00:00:00?

---

Per request, here's the `date-fns`-code for startOfMonth:

```
function startOfMonth (dirtyDate) {
  var date = parse(dirtyDate)
  date.setDate(1)
  date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0)
  return date
}
```

---

I really don't get why

```
var date = new Date();
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1, 1);
```

seem to work on feb-march but not on april?

Comment: My guess is you are running this in a different timezone than the one you are in

Comment: I don't think so, running it on my local computer and the error is reproduced with the wifi turned off.

Comment: Can you show the code for the function `startOfMonth`?

Comment: It's imported from the library `date-fns`, I'll update the question with the code for the function (as found in `node_modules`)

Comment: What does `parse(dirtyDate)` return?

Comment: This seems to be the issue still, I really don't understand date-fns..

Comment: @MrJalapeno
Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: @DapoMichaels Sorry for the late reply, but no I'm afraid not. Although I haven't been actively pursuing a solution for a few years now :)