# Trying to get first date of current month in html date picker

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hi I am trying to get first date of current month in HTML date picker.

```
From <input type="date" id="fdate" value=""/>
To<input type="date" id="tdate" value=""/>
```

I get today date in id="tdate like this given below but starting date of current month not able to get as I get current date.

```
var date = new Date();
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
var year = date.getFullYear();
if (month < 10) month = "0" + month;
if (day < 10) day = "0" + day;
var today = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
document.getElementById("tdate").value = today;
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
document.getElementById("tdate").value = firstDay;
```

Comment: the first date of any month is `1` - so you're doing that OK - you could just do `date.setDate(1)`

Comment: @JaromandaX i tried like this but not able to set the value in id=fdate                                        var firstDay = date.setDate(1);                                                           document.getElementById('tdate').value = firstDay;

Comment: You are setting  input with id 'tdate' twice! Shouldn't the last one be 'fdate' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`date` input fields must be in YYYY-MM-DD format. Your code:

```
var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
```

Will give back a string, e.g. `Tue Sep 01 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`, which is not what you want.

You can combine a couple of existing StackOverflow answers to accomplish what you want:

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/23593099/378779
function formatDate(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
    if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

    return [year, month, day].join('-');
}

// https://stackoverflow.com/a/13572682/378779
function getFstDayOfMonFnc() {
    var date = new Date();
    return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1)
}
```

Assuming `fdate` should be the first of the month and `tdate` should be today's date:

```
document.getElementById('fdate').value = formatDate( getFstDayOfMonFnc() );
document.getElementById('tdate').value = formatDate( new Date() );
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var date = new Date();

var monthStart = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth())
monthStart = toIsoDateString(monthStart);
console.log(monthStart);

var nextMonthStart = Date.UTC(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1);
nextMonthStart = toIsoDateString(nextMonthStart);
console.log(nextMonthStart);

function toIsoDateString(utcDate) {
  var date = new Date(utcDate);
  return date.toISOString().split('T')[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this as reference.

This is the code I used:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript Dates</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
         var date = new Date();
         document.write("Current Date: " + date );
         var firstDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 1);
         document.write("<br>"+firstDay);
         var lastDay = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth() + 1, 0);
         document.write("<br>"+lastDay);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

You can edit this code as suitable to your program.

Comment: i tried the code you mention but not able to st value in id=fdate

Comment: you'll have to work around the code. I would have edited the code, but Naveen's code is suitable. please let me know.