# get the first and last day of the month

Tags: javascript, node.js

this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery) however maybe something has changed as that no longer works.

```js
function firstAndLast() {
  const startDate = new Date(2020, 8, 1);
  const endDate = new Date(2020, startDate.getMonth() + 1, 0)

  console.log('startDate', startDate) // <-- 2020-08-31T22:00:00.000Z
  console.log('endDate', endDate) // <-- 2020-09-29T22:00:00.000Z
}

firstAndLast();
```

as the docs say the parameters are `new Date(YYYY, MM, DD, hh, mm, ss, ms)`

I am entering the year `2020` the month `august` (note this is node not browser) and day `1` the first of the month. What is going on here?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error, you can't repeat the `const` keyword like that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get first and last date of current month with JavaScript or jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13571700/get-first-and-last-date-of-current-month-with-javascript-or-jquery)

Comment: Your comments and the actual output differ - looks like it's working?

Comment: @Liam that's what I linked to, and that's the code that is posted there. However, if you run the code snippet you'll see the dates are not correct. There are not 29 days in September

Comment: @chazsolo i get startDate "2020-08-31T22:00:00.000Z"
endDate "2020-09-29T22:00:00.000Z" as outputs. there are not 29 days in September

Comment: It's converting to your local timezone, which subtracts a day

Comment: It's subtracting 2 hours.

Comment: @Barmar alright then it looks like I need to some how avoid this two hour subtraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to consider the Timezone offset.
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Date/getTimezoneOffset

```js
function firstAndLast() {
  const offset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60

  const startDate = new Date(2020, 8, 1, 0-offset);
  const endDate = new Date(2020, startDate.getMonth() + 1, 0, 0-offset)

  console.log('startDate', startDate) // <-- 2020-08-31T22:00:00.000Z
  console.log('endDate', endDate) // <-- 2020-09-29T22:00:00.000Z
}

firstAndLast();
```

Comment: thanks! I was looking up the offset but was mucking about with it and couldn't really figure out how to do it exactly, but, this works great! Thanks!